# who shows (unknown) user logged-in: what's going on?

Tags: users, who, w

In a RHEL 7.3 server, I was trying to find logged-in users. I ran `w` and it told me there were two users, but it only showed me the info of one (myself); then I ran `who`, which displayed the other user as (unknown). Finally, I ran `lastlog`, with which's output I could match the log in date and port from `who`'s output and find the unknown user actually is `gdm`.

```
$ w
 09:33:36 up 4 days, 15:22,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
myusr     pts/0    172.16.23.113    09:32    0.00s  0.06s  0.03s w

$ who
(unknown) :0           2017-07-01 18:13 (:0)
myusr     pts/0        2017-07-06 09:32 (172.16.23.113)

$ lastlog 
Username         Port     From             Latest
...
gdm              :0                        Sat Jul  1 18:13:23 -0500 2017
...
```

The server is a supermicro machine and from time to time I connect to it using IPMI2's kvm over lan feature. But I don't remember anything weird happening when connecting like that.

This doesn't seem normal. What could have happened?

Comment: Keep in mind, based on `info coreutils 'who invocation'` the `who` command just outputs the content of `/var/run/utmp`, which is supposed to reflect the current sessions. `who` is not really responsible for the content it outputs, it's just a clean way of showing it.

Comment: Someone had added an answer (now deleted) saying that a user without a shell in /etc/passwd would show as unknown. Do you, @Centimane (anybody), know anything about this?

Comment: It seems that answer was deleted based on my comment to it. `who` doesn't touch `/etc/passwd` at all, based on an `strace -e trace=file who 2>&1 | grep etc`

Comment: indeed it was a wild guess that I intended to check when I'll have a few spare time, Centimane corrected me before that so I deleted that wrong answer.

Comment: @M4rty Not all of the answer was wrong though, you were on the right track that the `gdm` login was being misinterpreted.

Comment: @Centimane Ok, thanks for the clarification. Your first comment was very helpful as well.

Comment: @M4rty Thanks for the effort anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading Centimane's comment on `/var/run/utmp` and searching differently, I found [this fedora forum thread](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=283842), which mentioned the issue is provoked by a bug in GDM, which creates a bad entry in `/var/run/utmp`. Eventually I even found a [bug report for it](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=12542) and [another here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=760834).

Answer (score 2):

It really seems like your unknown user is `gdm` and `who` somehow fail to interpret it.